# What is best to insert several values at the end of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, insert, c++20

To add elements to a `std::vector<int> v` is it better to do:

```
// Read and manipulate a, b, c triplet as ints.
// Potentially also: v.reserve(v.size() + 3); or trust vector growth policy?
v.push_back(a);
v.push_back(b);
v.push_back(c);
```

or

```
v.insert(v.end(), {a, b, c});
```

from a performance point of view (assuming we are always going to insert triplets that are different everytime and a large unfixed number of them, say 1 million triplets)? Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, doing `v.reserve(v.size() + 3);` in a loop is generally a very bad idea since it will certainly cause a new reallocations for each iteration. For example, both Clang and GCC with the libstdc++ and libc++ actually do a linear number of reallocations (see [here](https://quick-bench.com/q/p0pANYtPfJysQYwOiBoxiy-fIiU), [here](https://quick-bench.com/q/TTI-skzpNsqZX_SEurnGqE8X52c) or even [there](https://quick-bench.com/q/X6xll1rXlWrzlLQTOpVj--w8UlE)). Here is a quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve):

> Correctly using reserve() can prevent unnecessary reallocations, but inappropriate uses of reserve() (for instance, calling it before every push_back() call) may actually increase the number of reallocations (by **causing the capacity to grow linearly rather than exponentially**) and result in increased computational complexity and decreased performance. For example, a function that receives an arbitrary vector by reference and appends elements to it should usually not call reserve() on the vector, since it does not know of the vector's usage characteristics. 
> When inserting a range, the range version of **insert() is generally preferable as it preserves the correct capacity growth behavior**, unlike reserve() followed by a series of push_back()s. 
> reserve() *cannot be used to reduce the capacity of the container*; to that end shrink_to_fit() is provided.

When it comes to `insert` VS `push_back`s, `insert` should be slightly better than many `push_back` because the capacity check can be done only once as opposed to multiple `push_back`s. That being said, the performance difference is very dependent of the standard library implementation.

Comment: But is it safe to say that the `std::initializer_list<int>` version `{a, b, c}` is optimized out?

Comment: It may not. Actually, Clang seems not to optimize that which is a bit surprising (it generate a pretty bad code for both the push_back and the inserts). That being said, the cost of copying few integers (typically in the L1 cache) is negligible compared to the cost of inserting a lot of values in a `std::vector<int>`: the biggest overhead comes from the resizes bounded by the memory hierarchy (L3-cache/RAM and certainly page-faults).